# Serve Classic ASP in Blazor WebAssembly Hosted

Tags: asp-classic, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly Hosted site that I need to use to server up some classic ASP applications the customer needs to use until they are converted to Blazor.

I put the required asp files in the Client wwwroot folder. I then added the following logic to the server Program.cs file. What is happening is that it is serving up the full asp file, without processing it on the server to an html page. How do I get that to happen?

```
app.MapWhen(ctx => { var p = ctx.Request.Path.ToString(); return p.ToLower().EndsWith(".asp");  }, asp =>

{

    asp.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>

    {

        endpoints.MapControllers();

        endpoints.MapRazorPages();

        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

        endpoints.MapGet("/{Page}.asp", x =>

        {

            x.Response.Redirect("/{Page}.asp");

            return Task.CompletedTask;

        });

    });

});

 
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");


app.Run();
```

Comment: the client is not a asp.net server, try the server folder, be warned classic ASP may need an older unsupported version of the framework, perhaps a full IIS server setup

Comment: If I put the files in the server folder they are not even published to the web site, so this won't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not published to the website".  If you mean you're getting a 404 when you try to view an .asp page then it sounds like you don't have Classic ASP enabled on your server - it isn't enabled by default in current versions of IIS.  IIS will give you a 404 if a file with an unrecognised extension is requested.

Comment: @fuzzybear  Classic ASP needs IIS or IIS Express.  It has nothing to do with asp.net and doesn't need any version of the Framework, but it can run alongside .net stuff on the same server